# ModuleNotFoundError but module is installed

Tags: python

I have pip installed colorgram.py but I am still getting an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorgram'
```

I have also created a path to the python location:

`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`

`C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39/scripts`

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: use pip3? you're using python3

Comment: Go to your terminal and type `pip list` to see if you have installed `colorgram.py`. It will be listed if you have installed by typing `pip install colorgram.py` to your terminal

Comment: I have it, still comes up with the error.

Comment: open cmd in Admin mode and run command pip install cologram.py

Comment: Tried using admin mode and a pip3 install. still getting the error. I can see it in the site-packages folder but still getting the error on PyCharm.

Comment: Maybe, you are in the wrong environment. If you have `conda` base enviroment. Go there

Answer (score 3):

I guess you've installed the module with a different python version than you have run it. To fix this you can run `python -m pip install <the-name-of-the-module>` and than run the script with `python <path-to-your-script>`. If you want to use python3 just replace all `python` with `python3`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue recently by updating my $PYTHONPATH to match my site-packages. I couldn't use a module command from the commandline (e.g. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onelogin_aws_cli')

1. When you pip install the Module, note where it's already installed (e.g. Requirement already satisfied: onelogin-aws-cli==0.1.6 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.1.6))
2. Set your Python path to the location of the site packages (e.g. export $PYTHONPATH=./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages)

I was then able to use the onelogin_aws_cli command from the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue which brought me here.

I found a solution in my case. The package was installed, attempts to re-install said requirement already satisfied.

In my case the tool I was trying to use (pytest) was not installed in the venv but was installed in the path. Installing pytest into the same venv solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

same problem. Try to create a new project, it's probably you install colorgram.py after creating the project and the module is not contained in venv, installing colorgram.py from pycharm directly might help too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).