# "ModuleNotFoundError", but I can see the module?

Tags: python, dependencies, modulenotfounderror

I have been trying to install and use a library called [MakeGraphitics](https://github.com/velocirobbie/make-graphitics), but keep getting the same error message, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'read_lammpsdata'`, whenever I try to execute any of the examples available with the MakeGraphitics install:

[image: screenshot]

I am using Git Bash, but had the same exact issue when trying to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) instead. I feel like I understand how dependencies work. I am just confused because the "read_lammpsdata" module is indeed located in the correct directory, i.e., the directory indicated by the error message:

[image: screenshot]

I followed MakeGraphitic's suggested install pipeline exactly:

```
$ git clone github.com/velocirobbie/make-graphitics
$ cd make-graphitics
$ python setup.py install
$ pytest
```

And then:

```
$ cd examples
$ python graphene_sheet.py
```

Similar questions were asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458461/modulenotfounderror-but-module-is-installed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693420/python-modulenotfounderror-but-module-is-installed), but none of the responses solved my issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please carefully read [ask]. There are dozens of questions about ModuleNotFoundError daily. To make this question unique and answerable, include a [mre], the commands you used to install the  module and the exact command you use to execute your code. Also, don't post screenshots of code or errors, but copy-paste the text instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what the issue was, but I was able to get things working by creating a Python2.7 environment in Anaconda, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-and-3-on-mac-os), then following MakeGraphitics' suggested installation steps:

```
$ git clone github.com/velocirobbie/make-graphitics 
$ cd make-graphitics 
$ python setup.py install 
$ pytest
```

Partly my own fault, as MakeGraphitics clearly suggests to install using Python2.7.

Cheers!